# Angular2 remove script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

There are some problems using script-tags(`<script>`) on angular 2 that I face with.

**First** : I understand that angular 2 removes script tags from templates. I overcome this issue, writing my scripts in index.html. However, writing all the scripts in index.html make the code unreadable. How can I solve this problem ?

**Second** : When the first time index.html is loaded, my script works(written in index.html). But, after routing some other templates and back to index.html, my script don't work. I think the problem is related with routing but I am not sure.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <base href="/"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="bower_components/material-cards/dist/material-cards.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="bower_components/material-cards/js/jquery.material-cards.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.material-card')
                .materialCard({
                    icon_close: 'fa-chevron-left',
                    icon_open: 'fa-thumbs-o-up',
                    icon_spin: 'fa-spin-fast',
                    card_activator: 'click'
                });

            //    $('.active-with-click .material-card').materialCard();

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.material-card').materialCard();
                },
                2000);


        });
    </script>


    <link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/http.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<my-app>

</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',

    template: `
            <navbar></navbar> 
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                ` 
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        // You need this small hack in order to catch application root view container ref
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }

    getNotification(evt) {
        // <child (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child>
        console.log(evt);
    }
}
```

movies.component.ts

```
import { Component, Directive, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ContentChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from "./movies.service";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { NotificationService } from '../Shared/notification.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'movies2',
    templateUrl: '/templates/movies.component.html',
    providers: [MoviesService]
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {

    isLoading = true;
    movies: any = [];
    selectedMovie: any = {};

    constructor(private _moviesService: MoviesService, private router: Router, private notificationService: NotificationService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.GetMovies();
    }


    AddMovie() {
        this.router.navigate(['/newmovie']);
    }

    GetMovies() {
        this._moviesService.getMovies().subscribe(p => {
            this.movies = p;
        });
    }

    SelectMovie(mv: any) {
        this.selectedMovie = mv;
    }

    removeMovie(val: any) {
        this.notificationService.openConfirmationDialog('Are you sure you want to delete ' + val.MovieName + ' ?',
            () => {
                this._moviesService.deleteMovie(val).subscribe(res => {
                    this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage(val.MovieName + ' has been deleted.');
                    this.GetMovies();
                }, error => {
                    this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error);
                });
            });
    }

    removeMovieV2(val: any) {
        this._moviesService.deleteMovie(val).subscribe(res => {
            this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage(val.MovieName + ' has been deleted.');
            this.GetMovies();
        }, error => {
            this.notificationService.printErrorMessage(error);
        });
    }
}
```

movies.component.html

```
<section class="container">

    <div class="row active-with-click">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <article class="material-card Red">
                <h2>
                    <span>Christopher Walken</span>
                    <strong>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i>
                        The Deer Hunter
                    </strong>
                </h2>
                <div class="mc-content">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2691310/github/material-card/thumb-christopher-walken.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mc-description">
                        He has appeared in more than 100 films and television shows, including The Deer Hunter, Annie Hall, The Prophecy trilogy, The Dogs of War ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="mc-btn-action">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="mc-footer">
                    <h4>
                        Social
                    </h4>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus"></a>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <article class="material-card Pink">
                <h2>
                    <span>Sean Penn</span>
                    <strong>
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i>
                        Mystic River
                    </strong>
                </h2>
                <div class="mc-content">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2691310/github/material-card/thumb-sean-penn.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mc-description">
                        He has won two Academy Awards, for his roles in the mystery drama Mystic River (2003) and the biopic Milk (2008). Penn began his acting career in television with a brief appearance in a 1974 episode of Little House on the Prairie ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="mc-btn-action">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="mc-footer">
                    <h4>
                        Social
                    </h4>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></a>
                    <a class="fa fa-fw fa-google-plus"></a>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You may write script in `app.component` -> starting component. Will that help?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. If it's about your own code than just write it in TypeScript withing components or services. If it's about loading JS libraries, use require.js or similar to include the code.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Writing the script in  app.component is not working

Answer (score -2):

angular2 official site says "we remove script tags for security" but using of scripts are not written

Comment: I don't know if this answers the questions... Elaborate more on what you are trying to say...

Comment: could you elaborate your answer please