# Angular not showing my div content with external URL

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a piece of html code like this

```
<div 
  id='paysonContainer'
  url='https://test-www.payson.se/embedded/checkout?id=af1ebee5-40bd-410a-90d1-a94401553414'>
</div>

<script 
  type='text/javascript' 
  src='https://test-www.payson.se/embedded/Content/payson.js?v2'>
</script>
```

When I create a simple html file and paste this piece of html code there, there is no problem and I see what I am supposed to see, but when I copy the same html code to a view in an Angular app, the div is not loading and shows nothing. You can check it out here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bkbm6 (on hello.component.html ) If you want to see the difference create a simple html file on your machine, paste the code and open it on your browser.

Comment: [Angular remove scripts from templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792619/angular2-remove-script-tags). Consider declaring this script as an asset of your project.

Comment: @trichetriche I dont think that will work, as the script will be added to the head of the page, and there will be no corresponding `div`

Comment: If your script is added to the top of the page, then you should have no issue.

Comment: Why? As soon as the script executes, its going to look for the `paysonContainer` div, which isnt going to exist...

Comment: @all if you move them to the index.html page , script tag appears in the page source code , but it is still not showing anything on the browser

Comment: @Yashar It seems to have a problem with the closing tag, but it does work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkdqt6?file=src%2Findex.html. Just delete that closing tag and rewrite it

Comment: @user184994  yes it was a stupid mistake , but  what if I want to movie it to app.component.html or other component.html.       it will dissapear again.  I am getting the whole content together ( script and div) in run time and I should show it on the page , I have describe that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980322/appending-html-snippet-to-the-view-in-angular-6

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, script tags are not valid in Angular. Angular will rip them out. This is to prevent XSS attacks and so on.

If you want to load some JS then add it to your index.html file in the head section. Alternatively, add it to angular.json in the scripts section. If you go down the latter route you will need to do a Webpack restart.

Comment: I think script tag is not the problem , see my comment above